# onOpen() not working - getting permissions error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the code here at the top of a Google Apps Script that is container-bound to a Google Sheet file:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Payroll')
    .addItem('Add shoot days', 'copyCallSheets')
    .addItem('Update Call Sheet/Crew List', 'updateDocs')
    .addItem('Create Daily Time Sheet', 'sendDailyTimeSheets')
    .addItem('Collect Out Times from DTS', 'collectOuttimez')
    .addItem('Process Timecards', 'processTimecardz')
    .addSeparator()
    .addItem('Report Issue', 'sendErrorReport')
    .addToUi();
}
```

When I open my file, however, the `onOpen()` simple trigger fails, and I get this error message:

> Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFileById. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive)
> at unknown function

Any of the functions I'm calling in the menu work just fine if I call them by manually executing them in the script, but I want to be able to have the user call them from the UI.

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image: Error Log]

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. P.S. The `onOpen` function is not failing, the error comes from a statement that is using `DriveApp`. Are you using global variables? Is your project using the default GCP project or an standard GCP project?

Comment: Is your script bound to a GCP project? If you view the `appsscript.json` file to you have any oauth2scopes?

Comment: I am using global variables... I haven't done anything with GCP, so I'm assuming it is using the default? I'm not sure how to access the appscript.json file?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'global variables' or at least, why it's relevant here. You should read up more on GCP projects and how they tie to Apps Script projects [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects).

Comment: Thanks, @RafaGuillermo. The global variables comment was in response to Rubén's question. Reading that documentation you sent, I am using a default GCP project. Not seeing any reason why I would need to use a Standard GCP project instead, based on that documentation, but maybe I am missing something

Answer (score 2):

Simple triggers cannot perform functions that required permissions

[Simple Trigger Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers?hl=en#restrictions)

Comment: Thanks @Copper. The onOpen() function is not performing any functions that require permissions, as you can see from my code. It is just creating a menu in the UI

Comment: maybe you have another onOpen() somewhere.

Comment: No, there's just the one.

Answer (score 2):

Was able to get this to work by creating an installable trigger. Still unsure why it stopped working as a simple trigger, however (it was working fine for a while).