# onOpen function not launching in the duplicated Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

My onOpen() function adds 2 buttons in the taskbar of Google Sheets. It used to work perfectly and the buttons appeared even in duplicated sheets. But suddenly it stopped appearing in duplicated files.

What I am currently doing is adding a trigger every time I duplicate the sheet to open it. But I have to run the onOpen() function otherwise it doesn't work.

My function is very simple and basic

```
function onOpen() {
 
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  ui.createMenu('Present Data')
    .addItem("Generate Report",'report')
    .addToUi();

  ui.createMenu('Reset')
    .addItem("Meta","resetmetaFunction")
    .addItem("Snapchat","resetsnapFunction")  
    .addItem("TikTok","resettiktokFunction")
    .addItem("Twitter","resettwitterFunction")
    .addItem("Youtube","resetyoutubeFunction")  
    .addItem("Google","resetgoogleFunction")
    .addItem("LinkedIn","resetlinkedinFunction")  
    .addItem("Programmatic","resetprogrammaticFunction")        
    .addItem("Clear All","resetAll")      
    .addToUi();
}
```

What could possibly cause the script to stop running on startup ?

Comment: Did you check the Executions tab (present in left menu of the script editor) to see if it is running on startup but somehow failing? And does the script in your duplicated sheet have any global variables that require authorization?

Comment: As @ab.it.gcp mentioned, could you provide us a screenshot of the execution log or in the [Apps script dashoard](https://script.google.com/home/executions). Usually, you will see more information or error messages registered there.

Comment: @ab.it.gcp Thank you for your response. I checked the Executions tabs, and in the duplicated sheet, it mentions that the onOpen timed out with the following error: "Exceeded maximum execution time" - To your second question, if I understood it correctly, my script does not have global variables that require authorization. I am just calling  Google Sheets and Google Slides and nothing external.

Comment: @GiselleValladares Thank you for your response. I'd love to share a screenshot but I don't have the right permissions on the forum as of yet.

Comment: @ab.it.gcp I forgot to mention that I am also calling DriveApp. And after re-duplicating the initial sheet. The duplicated sheet had this error in its Executions Tab: "Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFileById. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive)"

Comment: @Karim, maybe you can use an app to store images and post the link? Like Google Drive, Dropbox or something similar.

Comment: @GiselleValladares https://imgur.com/2CTkrES

Comment: @GiselleValladares And here's the other error https://imgur.com/tLduDvT

Comment: @Karin, one question just to confirm, since you are creating the sheet, your user is the owner of the sheet, and you have permission to edit it. Is that correct?

Comment: @GiselleValladares I am the owner of the sheet and I want to share it with my team members. But I am currently testing it by duplicating it to see how the onOpen can appear. But I think I found the answer. Since I am calling DriveApp, the simple trigger onOpen() function is not firing because it has restricted permissions. So I think DriveApp is mainly what is preventing it to fire. Do you think this can be solved some way or another ? To maybe force the script to trigger for example a Trigger and make it behave like a Simple Trigger ?

Comment: @Karim, Thanks for the information, I will post an answer in a few minutes with a workaround that might help you. Please let me know if it doesn't so I can do some more tests, and update the answer.

Comment: @GiselleValladares Thank you so much for your time and efforts! Sure I will let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest the behavior when just duplicating the sheet, should still run the  `onOpen()`, and allow you to see the menu and allow you to see it. However, when clicking on the menu it should request the permissions to access Google Drive and anything else required to run the script. You can report that issue by following the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#developer_product_feedback)

*Note: This is taking into consideration that you have editing permissions in the Google Sheet, and you have access to the Drive file called by `DriveApp.getFileById()`.*

Since the script is not authorized yet, and is not triggering the authentication You can try these workarounds for the moment.

The normal flow when you run the script for the first time, you should get an OAuth screen to authorize all the scopes needed by the script. To force this, you have 3 options, first try to run the script manually to force the Authentication of the Script. Using `Run`.

[image: run]

[image: OAuth]

---

The second option is to programmatically create an installable trigger. Something like:

```
function createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onOpen')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onOpen()
      .create();
}
```

Before the:

```
function onOpen() {
 
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  ui.createMenu('Present Data')
    .addItem("Generate Report",'report')
    .addToUi();

  ui.createMenu('Reset')
    .addItem("Meta","resetmetaFunction")
    .addItem("Snapchat","resetsnapFunction")  
    .addItem("TikTok","resettiktokFunction")
    .addItem("Twitter","resettwitterFunction")
    .addItem("Youtube","resetyoutubeFunction")  
    .addItem("Google","resetgoogleFunction")
    .addItem("LinkedIn","resetlinkedinFunction")  
    .addItem("Programmatic","resetprogrammaticFunction")        
    .addItem("Clear All","resetAll")      
    .addToUi();
}
```

---

Last option that you can do is to [manually add the scope](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes
s) on the Apps script Manifest by following the steps:

1. Open the script project.
2. At the left, click `Project Settings` (gear icon).
3. Select the Show "appsscript.json" manifest file in editor checkbox.
4. At the left, click `Editor` code.
5. At the left, click the `appsscript.json` file.
6. Locate the top-level field labeled `oauthScopes`. If it's not present, you can add it.
7. The `oauthScopes` field specifies an array of strings. To set the scopes your project uses, replace the contents of this array with the scopes you want it to use.

```
        "oauthScopes": [
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drivel"
        ]
```

And it will look like this:

[image: manifest]

Comment: Giselle thank you so much for your kind effort. But unfortunately none of the above 2 methods worked. I have added all your methods in this sheet. This is a duplicated sheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19BsGfbTaBL4yIXAFlKZa4Hra35jc-SMC_lNW610TWjg/edit#gid=328997568

Comment: @Karim, thanks for the update. Could you provide me a screenshot of the manifest?

Comment: I apologize but I'm not sure what would you like me to take as a screenshot. If you are talking about the execution tab. It gave me the same issue as this: imgur.com/2CTkrES

Comment: no, it will be to add this checkmark in the apps script https://imgur.com/a/NueDyRo and after that go to `Editor` > `appsscript.json`. also, if possible could you take a screenshot of the `Project OAuth Scopes` under `Overview` (The `i` icon) like this https://imgur.com/a/vKJTqUZ

Comment: Sure, here's a link : https://imgur.com/a/N2VnlMv

Comment: It seems super odd, I just ran the test with 2 workspace accounts and 1 gmail.com account. And it works as expected for me. If you create a new Google Sheet and copy and paste the script, do you have the same issue? I think you should really report the issue.

Comment: thank you for the update. We you say you ran the test, did you run it with the spreadsheet I shared with you ?

Comment: No, I copy the snippet of the code, I made different functions with the names of the menus. They only had a basic `DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getName()` for each function.

Comment: After that, I made a copy of the Google sheet, and it works for me.

Comment: I'm trying to do that right now. I'll keep you updated

Comment: hello, I have took the time to redo the sheets from scratch, from a completely new srpeadsheet. And the problem still persists. I don't think it's a bug, because it's only when I link a function that uses DriveApp in the onOpen function that the buttons disappear after duplication. With it, I am still receiving the following error for the Simple Trigger, in the Exectutions tab of the duplicated sheet : "Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFileById. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive)"

Comment: and of course I have manually added the scope like you have showed me, and it still shows this error. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Let me review if I can found something else.

Comment: thank you so much. Also I realized, that even if the function that has DriveApp.getFilebyID() is not related whatsoever with the onOpen function, I still get the error and the menus dont appear in duplicated sheets. But if i mute this function that has DriveApp, the menus appear successfully.  I also bumped into this stackoverflow link which seems to have the same issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67038943/onopen-not-working-getting-permissions-error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252445/discussion-between-giselle-valladares-and-karim).

Comment: how are you ? I want to share this finding with you. I found out why I  was having the error : "Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFileById. Required permissions: (googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || googleapis.com/auth/drive)"

It was because I had the var DriveApp.getFileById as a Global Variable. When I removed it and inserted inside a function. The problem completely disappeared. 

I just wanted to share this with you since you have helped me :) Thank you and wishing you a great end of week!

Comment: Thank you so much for the information, that will help me a lot from now on. I learn something new,